# mysql++ insert how to?

Tags: c++, mysql++

I am having problem to INSERT some values into database. Database name is users, and table is heroes. I am doing some mmorpg game developing for purpose of learning.

This is mysql code that works

```
INSERT INTO heroes (HeroID,Strenght, Dexterity, Vitality, Wisdom, Inteligence, Luck, Name, Level, XP) VALUES (NULL,  17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, 'works', 4, 3750);
```

But when I try that from c++ via mysql++ I get error.

Code:

```
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Connect to the database.
mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);

if (conn.connect("users", "localhost",
        "root", "toor")) 
{

    mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
   query << "INSERT INTO heroes" <<
    "VALUES (NULL, 17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, doSomething,3, 3260);";

    query.execute();
    if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store()) 
    {
     // nothing to do here
    }

    else 
    {
        cerr << "Failed to get item list: " << query.error() << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

   else 
    {
    cerr << "DB connection failed: " << conn.error() << endl;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Error I get is: Failed to get item list; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL, 17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, doSOmething,3, 3260)' at line 1

p.s. I am sending NULL becouse that field is auto-increment (using for ID) 
 I tried almost all possible alternatives like adding '', separataning and whatnot. Can somebody help me with this line of code, since I can't find ang good tutorial that helps on this matter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to add an space in your string?

```
query << "INSERT INTO heroes " <<
    "VALUES (NULL, 17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, 'doSomething', 3, 3260);";
```

Also, as pointed out by [hmjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033896/hmjd), `doSomething` needs to be quoted, like `'doSomething'`.

Comment: tried that, didnt work 30 mins ago, now works. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The string `doSomething` needs quoted:

```
query << "INSERT INTO heroes "
      << "VALUES (NULL, 17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, 'doSomething', 3, 3260);";
```

and as pointed out by [Streppel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670308/streppel) a space is required between `heroes` and `VALUES`.

Comment: @Streppel, chuckle. :)

Comment: Yes, that was last try, and now i added fields after heroes (NameID ....) thanks Steppel, hmjd, Bartdude.

Answer (score 2):

If your field is auto-increment, just don't mention it in your query, and that's it !

But then you would need to name all the fields in your insert query, which is actually a best-practice anyway !

```
query << "INSERT INTO heroes (fieldName1,fieldName2,...) " <<
"VALUES (17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, doSomething,3, 3260);";
```

Where fieldname1 is your first field right after the id field (or any other field actually, you can use whatever order you wish).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a header and paste this in. i will use table1.h

```
#include <mysql++.h>
#include <ssqls.h>
#include <vector>       

    //you may get some weird underlines but don't panic, have some vitality.
    sql_create_10(heroes, 1, 10,
            mysqlpp::sql_int, HeroId, mysqlpp::sql_int,
            Strenght, mysqlpp::sql_int, Dexterity, mysqlpp::sql_int, Vitality,
            mysqlpp::sql_int, Wisdom, mysqlpp::sql_int, Inteligence,
            mysqlpp::sql_int, Luck, mysqlpp::sql_varchar, Name, mysqlpp::sql_int,
            Level, mysqlpp::sql_bigint, Xp)
            //if bigint doesn't work for you u can use just int.
```

then in the main method paste this in

```
    //connect to database
mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
try{
    conn.connect("users", "localhost", "j0y57/Qxx", "rootsman");

    heroes row(0, 17, 13, 17, 15, 9, 8, "doSomething", 3, 3260 );
    mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
    query.insert(row);
    query.execute();

} catch (const mysqlpp::BadQuery& bq){
    cerr << "query error: " << bq.what() << endl;
    return -1;
}
```